# Vite React App - Won't load img with external url

Tags: reactjs, vite

I tried using the Vite development server to run a React app.

When I try to load an image with an external URL, such as:
`<img src="https://i.imgur.com/73hZDYK.png" />`

Inside a `.jsx` element, the image fails to load.

I notice looking at the Network tab in the DevTools, I get `403 Forbidden`.

I am not sure why?

The exact same component in a `create-react-app` will display the image no problems.

Any ideas?

Thank you

EDIT: Figuring out its CORS... but don't understand why or how to get through it?

EDIT 2: Adding `vite.config.json` (I didn't add anything)

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react-swc';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
});
```

EDIT3: adding component:

```
<header class="tweet--header">
  <img class="tweet--avatar" src="https://i.imgur.com/73hZDYK.png" />
  <h2 class="tweet--name">Newton</h2>
  <small class="tweet--handle">@SirIsaac</small>
</header>
```

Comment: share your `vite.config.js` file, it's most likely missing a configuration

Answer (score 0):

If it's happening with just Vite as you mentioned, your `vite.config.js` is most likely missing a configuration, as I just tested the image and it works.

Otherwise, it's most likely a **Mixed Content error**.

Browsers typically have strict policies that deny loading resources between HTTP and HTTPS. So, it's most likely because you are on **localhost** (aka HTTP) and you want to load from `https://i.imgur.com` (aka HTTPS).

It can also be the CORS policies on the server hosting your image i.e., `https://i.imgur.com` denies access to its resources from HTTP.

**Solutions:**

- Use HTTP for both of them i.e. download your image to your computer to use it during development.
- Check the CORS policies for the image server. It may not allow access from HTTP, so you should download the file.

Comment: Thank you for checking. you built the app with Vite as well? Did you add anything to your `vite.config.json` yourself?
What I don't understand is building the exact same page with `create-react-app` loaded the image on https no problems.

Comment: Yes, I built mine with Vite and your config is similar to mine, so the problem was not Vite as you’ve now discovered. 

Also, it worked for the CRA version because you most likely used the localhost address directly, as opposed to the ip address. @m3.b

Answer (score 0):

So actually, I found a way to make it work.

after running `npm run dev`, the shell suggest an address for the `Local`, to visit the project, with an IP:port such as `HTTP://127...`

If I replace the IP with `localhost:<port>`, the images will load.

Hmmhmm

Comment: oh, if you were using your local IP address as opposed to localhost, it was definitely the *Mixed content error*. Using the localhost address itself (i.e localhost:3000 for example) bypasses the HTTP/HTTPS mix then